# React router 4 url issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-v4

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from './history';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';
import NotFound from './presentation/NotFound';
import MainContent from './components/MainContent';
import Overview from './components/Overview';

export default () => {
    return(
        <Router history ={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
                <Home>
                    <Route path="/main" exact component={MainContent} />
                    <Route path="/admin/:id" exact component={Overview} />
                </Home>
                <Route component={ NotFound } />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

my webpack config is

```
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: 'babel-loader',test: /\.js$/,exclude: /node_modules/},
{
            test: /\.s?css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
            'file-loader',
            ],
        },{
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
        }, {
            test: /\.ttf$/,
            loader: "file-loader?limit=10000"
        }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __CLIENT__: JSON.stringify(true),
            __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
            __DEVTOOLS__: true
        }),
    ],
    optimization:{}
};
```

So when i land on `/main` i.e. MainContent component it renders a `ViewComponent` which renders a list of admins and on click of an individual element of the list it gives the detailed view of the that element on the `/admin/:id` route which works fine.

> but if i refresh or hit the url directly from the address bar, the
>   fonts' and the images' network request that were being rendered initially
>   from `localhost:8080/somerandomid.ttf` are now retrieved from
>   `localhost:8080/admin/somerandomid.ttf` throws a 400 bad request error and the styles change.

can anybody suggest how to rectify this error. i am calling a function and passing the id on click of an element from the list.

> this.props.history.push('/admin/' + id);

and that `ViewComponent` is which renders the admin list is connected as `export default withRouter(ViewComponent);` to get this.props.history.push.

> same goes with the image url too. localhost:8080/otherandomid.png is replaced and tried to get > from localhost:8080/admin/otherandomid.png and throws a 400 bad request error with no image 
>   displaying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a base URL.

It can be done with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __CLIENT__: JSON.stringify(true),
        __DEVELOPMENT__: true,
        __DEVTOOLS__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        base: '/'
    }),
],
```

Or directly in the `<head>` of your `index.html` file:

```html
<base href="/">
```

Comment: had tried this. but still gave me the same response